# Typeahead.js Basic With MySQL DB

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, typeahead.js

I am following a tutorial online (http://mycodde.blogspot.co.uk/2013/12/typeaheadjs-autocomplete-tutorial-ajax.html#comment-form) which invloves typeahead.js and a simple MySQL DB and I cannot get it to work.

Using typeahead.js v10.2 jQuery v1.9.1 and Bootstrap v3.2.0

I have included the necessary css and js files, I have also created a connection.php file, which successfully connects to my localhost db.

The problem is that the auto-suggest box doesn't auto-suggest anything. I am possibly doing something silly as I am new to js and programming.

I have included my files below if anybody would be kind enough to point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<title>Typeahead.js Tutorial with Mysql Database</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="generator" content="Geany 1.23.1" />
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" name="search" id="search"></div>       
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.10.2/bloodhound.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.10.2/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.10.2/typeahead.jquery.js"></script> 
<script>
$("document").ready(function(){
    $("#search").typeahead({
        name : 'sear',
        remote: {
            url : '/connection.php?query=%QUERY'
        }

    });
});
</script>

</html>
```

connection.php

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","myuser","mypassword","mydb");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT first_name,last_name FROM actor");

while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
            $user_arr[] = $row->first_name;
            $user_arr2[] = $row->last_name;

}

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

When I check the firebug console I get an *Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function* appears at line 22 which is;

```
$("#search").typeahead({
```

Can anybody lend some assistance?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check you jquery DOM Ready bind handler syntax here:

```
$("document").ready(...
```

It must be

```
$( document ).ready(...
```

Read more:
http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Thanks @itnelo - I have now changed this, that particular error has disappeared from the console log, however it still won't work. I have made sure all of my scripts are up to date, and amended my original post accordingly.

Comment: Your php script collects data from DB but I not see transfering data from server to client, in jquery ajax callback, where this data should be printed to page. Are you sure what in this moment your server do "echo json data" operation?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following code in your .js file:

```
    var search = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('sear'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    limit: 10,
    remote: {
        url: '/connection.php?query=%QUERY',

        filter: function(list) {
            return $.map(list, function(search) {
                return {
                    name: sear
                };
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The json file contains an array of strings, but the Bloodhound
suggestion engine expects JavaScript objects so this converts all of those strings.